# "Manage Public List Views" permission missing from Profile SObject

Tags: salesforce

I am writing a visualforce page that amoung other things allows creation of Queues. However I want to control whether the section is displayed depending on whether the user has the permissions required.

According to the docs: [Creating Queues](http://na10.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/setting_up_queues.htm) the user needs to have both permissions:

1. "Customize Application"
2. "Manage Public List Views"

I am querying the profile like so:

```
Profile profile = [
    SELECT
        PermissionsCustomizeApplication
        //Was expecting: PermissionsManagePublicListViews
    FROM
        Profile
    WHERE
        Id = :UserInfo.getProfileId()];
```

However my problem is that I don't think the "Manage Public List Views" permission is exposed on the Profile object. Is the api name so different I am missing it? Does anyone know how to check for this permission in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to limit it just to people with the "Customise Application" profile option.

The reason being that this is the important profile option. The only reason people need the public list views options is because a new view is created for each new queue.

As I have discovered there is no crud security on the queue object in apex code. So restricting queue creation only to users with "Customise Application" seems like the safest and most flexible course of action.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the name of the permission, but you could run an method to try and insert (and then delete!) a queue in an init method or similar, if it success then you know they have all of the relevant permissions required.

The snag here of course, is you may not want them to be able to delete queues (I'm assuming they work in the manner of the other objects in the system with respect to CRUD operations).

Comment: This wasn't what I was looking for. But if it's my only option it's what I may have to do.

Comment: I implemented this suggestion without success, your assumption about CRUD operations on queues is incorrect. With sharing does nothing to prevent the creation of a queue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check for these permissions in code, and Lancey Snr's suggestion is probably the easiest work around. However, I personally don't like the idea of checking permissions by creating and deleting objects in the constructor.

I'd instead create a custom setting to track the Profiles (maybe as plain text) that are allowed to create profiles. The advantage of custom settings is that the administrator can update the custom setting when a new profile is created or an old one is deleted, or the permissions have been re-configured.

Use the custom setting in conjunction with the "with sharing" keyword in the controller code, and you can ensure that users who don't have permission to create Queues, won't be be able to create it.

Anup

Comment: This is going to part of a managed package. So custom settings are not feasible, due to the complexity of setting up the custom settings